# Proving linear transformation is one to one if vectors in vector space are linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

I have a linear transformation $F: U \to V$. Given that the vectors $\vec{v_1}...\vec{v_n} \in V$ are linearly independent I want to show that $F$ is one-to-one.
Also $F(\vec{u_i}) = \vec{v_i}$ and $\vec{u_i} \text{ form the basis of } U$ $\forall i  = 1,2,...,n$.
My approach was

$$s_1\vec{v_1}+...+s_n\vec{v_n} = \vec{0} \iff  s_1 = .... =s_n = 0 $$
$$\implies s_1F(\vec{u_1})+...+s_nF(\vec{u_n}) = \vec{0}$$
$$ \implies F(s_1\vec{u_1}+...+s_n\vec{u_n}) = \vec{0}$$

Thus $s_1\vec{u_1}+...+s_n\vec{u_n} \in \text{Ker } F$
and since $s_1 = .... =s_n =0$ we have $\vec{0} \in \text{Ker} F.$
In my course, I have proved if $\text{Ker} F = \vec{0} $  then F is one-to-one.

My question is whether my proof is correct or if I need to show that $F$ cannot contain any other vector other than the zero vector. If yes how shall I do it ?

Comment: you've not defined what $u_i$'s are, also what you've done doesn't show $F$ is one-one. You just proved that $0 \in \mathrm{Ker}F$ which is trivial. What you need to show is if $u \in \mathrm{Ker}F$ i.o.w $Fu = 0$ then prove $u=0$. But you've also not defined your $F$ properly in question

Comment: All the $u_i$'s form the basis of the vector space $U$ and I define F as it was defined in my book as a linear transformation from $U$ to $V$.  @Harsh

Comment: So If $u_i$'s form a basis of $U$ then, $F(s_1 u_1 + \ldots s_n u_n) = 0 \implies s_1 F(u_1) + \ldots + s_n F(u_n) = s_1 v_1 + \ldots + s_n v_n = 0$ and you mentioned $v_i$'s are L.I. then $s_1 = \cdots s_n = 0$ and thus $ \mathrm{Ker} F = \{0\}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a valid proof.

If you look closely you have only proven that
$$ 0 \in \ker F$$
which is always the case for *any* linear map.

What you need to prove is that the kernel of $F$ contains *only* $0$. That is, you must be prove that $\ker F = 0$. One way to do this is to pick any vector $ u \in \ker F$ and prove that it must be equal to $0$.

Let $u \in \ker F \subset U$. Since $\{u_i\}_{i=1}^n$ forms a basis for $U$ there exists $\lambda_1,...\lambda_n$ such that
$$ u = \sum_i \lambda_i u_i.$$

Since we know that $u \in \ker F$ we therefore have

$$ F(u) = 0 \iff \sum_i \lambda_i F(u_i) = 0 \iff \sum_i \lambda_i v_i = 0.$$

Using the linear of independence of $v_i$ you should be able to conclude that $u = 0$.